# How to load Tensorflow 1.x saved model in TensorFlow 2.x?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I have run code of TensorFlow 1.x.It works fine.Now I have generated checkpoint of that code.They also work fine.**Now I want to run these check point in my TensorFlow 2.x file**

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>         1 
>   ----> 2 loaded = tf.saved_model.load("/content/model/")
>         3 
>         4 
>         5
>
> 1 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py
>   in parse_saved_model(export_dir)
>        81                   (export_dir,
>        82                    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PBTXT,
>   ---> 83                    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
>        84 
>        85
>
> OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at:
>   /content/model//{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

This is error
Code 
    loaded = tf.saved_model.load("/content/model/")

**Share your view how can we solve this error**

[This is my file hierarchy,how I uploaded files on colab."model" folder is containing ckpt files of machine learning model in tensorflow 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bHO9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done.  Tensorflow 2 is largely backwards incompatible with Tensorflow 1.

Comment: "Additionally, SavedModels or stored GraphDefs will be backward compatible. SavedModels saved with 1.x will continue to load and execute in 2.x. " This is a line from their blog. 

https://medium.com/tensorflow/whats-coming-in-tensorflow-2-0-d3663832e9b8

I am also looking for an answer to this question. In their blog, they said it will be backward compatible in terms of loading the saved model.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it would work in this case but sometimes adding `tf.compat.v1.[desired command]` can make it work while using tensorflow 2.

E.g. `tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load`

In your case it may be worth trying:

```
loaded=tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load("/content/model/")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late to respond to this question. But I think my answer may help others who are looking for running TensorFlow Version-1 scripts on TensorFlow Version-2. Use the below commands instead of `import tensorflow as tf`

**New Commands:**

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
```